# incompatible types error on ListView of custom objects

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a ListView of custom objects (`MyCustomObj`) and I am using a custom adapter. The ListView displays the list of objects perfectly.

I want to update an individual item in the list when an event occurs. So in the activity, I have:

```
private ListView parentLayout;
MyCustomObj customObj;
```

And then I am trying to pass an index `i` to access the specific item to be updated as follows:

```
customObj = parentLayout.getAdapter().getItem(i);
```

But this generates the error `incompatible types. Required: MyCustomObj, Found: java.lang.Object`

So I change the object initialization to:

```
Object customObj
```

The error goes away, but the object actually appears to be a `MyCustomObj`, because when I output `customObject` to console, the output is `com.myapp.MyCustomObj@12ab34cd`.

But setters/getters are not available on this object in Android Studio since it's an `Object` and not a `MyCustomObj`.

For example, if I want to change the id attribute, normally I'd do this:

`customObj.setId(123);`  but this leads to `cannot resolve` errors even though `setId` is a proper setter in `MyCustomObj` class.

What's the proper way to access an individual object and update it, and why is the console showing the custom object? (I understand that after updating the object I will need to execute `notifyDataSetChanged()` )

The adapter looks something like this:

```
public class MyCustomManager extends ArrayAdapter<MyCustomObj> {
    public MyCustomManager(Context context, ArrayList<MyCustomObj> customObjects) {
        super(context, 0, customObjects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View customView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        MyCustomObj customObj = getItem(position);

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (customView == null) {
            customView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.template_my_custom_view, parent, false);
        }

        // Sets the tag
        customView.setTag(customObj.getId());

        //other view stuff goes here

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return customView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code of adapter class

Comment: @PankajKumar adapter class code has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cast the object as `MyCustomObj`

```
MyCustomObj  customObj = (MyCustomObj) parentLayout.getAdapter().getItem(i);
```